# How to post single perameter in zend framwork?

Tags: zend-framework

I have api controller and it logout method

```
 public function logoutAction()
    {
      if(!$this->getRequest()->isPost())
      {
          $response= $this->getResponse();
          $response->setHttpResponseCode(406);
          return $this->_helper->json->sendJson(array('status'=>'false'));
      }
      else
      {
         $data=$this->_request->getParams();

      }
    }
```

When i posting id with some value(assume we take id= 5) then $data['id'] value showing wrong value 5id=5 instead of only 5.

But when i posting multiple parameter with value like id=5,name=abc etc then id value display true value 5.I need to post only one id.help please ...thanks

Comment: Can you share the view script? How are you displaying the value of $data['id']? Not related to your question - is there a reason why you are accessing the request object in 2 different ways?

Comment: I not require view so i have disabled layout in controller's constructor.i have  defined $data['id'] from $data=$this->_request->getParams(); in else part of logout action.i just echo it value and exit

Comment: Would it not make sense to share code that you have problems with? Code above will not display values from the request. Where is the data coming from and what method did you use?

Comment: I am sending data using Firefox addon RESTeasy or curl using api